# JQuery: pass in arguments to plugin to restrict code execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, arguments

I'm new to JQuery, and am wondering how exactly I should pass in parameters to a plugin that will restrict which code inside of the plugin gets executed?

Basically, I want to call the plugin in one of two ways:

```
$(".element").plugin(optionA);
$(".element").plugin(optionB);
```

**UPDATE:**

If I call optionA, a dropdown menu appears when you type in text in a text field which, after selection, filters a table.  If I call optionB, the dropdown menu does not appear, but instead filters the table automatically.  So both options offer different functionality on the same object.  Essentially, I only want optionA code within the plugin to be executed if I pass in the optionA argument, and I only want optionB code within the plugin to be executed if I pass in optionB.

Here is the basic plugin structure:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.plugin = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({

            //Default Settings

        }, options);
        return this.each(function () {

            //Do some code here

        });
    };
 } (jQuery));
```

So my question is:

**Where do I pass in the parameter?**

Do I need to do something like below?

```
    (function ($, optionA, optionB) { ...
```

Then when I return the .each() function, do something like:

```
return this.each (function () {
    if (optionA) { //execute code}
    else if (optionB) { //execute code}
};
```

Or is it more like this:

```
return this.each ( function (optionA) {

    //Do optionA code here

});

return this.each ( function (optionB) {

    //Do optionB code here
});
```

Or is it neither?? If so, how is it done?

Comment: What is different between optionA and optionB?  are they completely different types? or they are both object with different keys?

Comment: You pass them in the options object...

Comment: @AlexCheuk If I understand your question correctly, they are the same object, but come with different functionality.  So for instance, optionA will show a dropdown menu and optionB will not.  Both involve the same object.

Comment: @Keven ok, now after the edit it's more clear what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UpUTafIb/7/edit)**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.plugin = function (options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
          filter : "optionA"   // use A by default
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {

           if(settings.filter == "optionA"){
               // DO SOMETHING HERE BY DEFAULT
           }else if(settings.filter == "optionB"){
               // DO SOMETHING IF "optionB" WAS SET
           }

        });
    };
 }(jQuery)); 



$(function(){ // DOM READY

  // $(".element").plugin();                   // will use A
  // $(".element").plugin({filter:"optionA"}); // will use A
  // $(".element").plugin({filter:"optionB"}); // will use B

});
```

Comment: This sounds like it would work for simple key/value pairs, but would it work if I want to change functionality?  For instance, if it is optionA I want the plugin to execute only optionA code.  If it is optionB I want it to only execute optionB code.

Comment: Thanks.  This solution would cover it if I were only passing in simple keys.  However, the optionA and optionB would restrict which code is executed inside of the plugin.  That's really what I need.

Comment: @Keven can you please just explain what should `optionA` and `optionB` be? and Object? String? or more like an instruction "please do whatever `optionB` does."

Comment: Sure.  I will try to articulate that in my question above.

Comment: See the paragraph after the Update: for an explanation of the functionality I would like to accomplish.  I really just want to know how to restrict which code is run inside of the function based on the argument call. So `if (optionA) { Do this } else if (optionB) { Do this }`

Comment: Perfect.  That is exactly what I needed.  It makes sense now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, one last question, which goes back to my original.  How can you call "optionA" or "optionB" without first passing it in as a function argument? I notice that you used `if(settings.filter == "optionA")` but how does this particular function know what "optionA" even is?

Comment: @Keven really simply: instead of `filter : false ` tell your settings that filter should use `"optionA"` (by default) instead of `false` . Just, than you don't need the `else`. http://jsbin.com/UpUTafIb/5/edit

Comment: Thanks.  I'm including the link to your previous code as well for reference purposes, because both are helpful.  http://jsbin.com/oBazARaR/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var options = {
     optionA: value1,
     optionB: value2,
     optionC: value3,
};
```

and

```
$(".element").plugin(options);
```

just like the `css` function:

```
$(".element").css({color:"#f65", display:"block"});
```